# css how to set a different color in the navbar for current page?

Tags: css, html, uinavigationbar

Hello I'm new to html & css and I have a problem. I made a navbar and wanted to show the user on wich page he was by changing the background-color in the navbar. But for some reason this doens't work very well. Please help me.

This is the css code I use for the navbar:

```css
#nav{
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}
/* unorded list */
#nav ul{}

#nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 62px;
}
/* text in blokken */
#nav ul li a{
  padding: 20px;
  background: orange;
  color: white;
}

 #nav ul li a:hover{
  background-color: #ff1e42;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #666;
  text-decoration: underline;
 }
#nav ul li #inuse {
  background-color: #ff1e42;
}
```

my html code looks like this:

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="inuse" href="../html/index.html" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="../html/kleding.html" >Kleding</a></li>
        <li><a href="../html/bestel.html" >Bestellen</a></li>
        <li><a href="../html/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="../html/vragen.html" >Vragen</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
#nav ul li a.inuse{/* in use css */}
```

instead of:

```
#nav ul li #inuse{}
```

hope that helps

Comment: It works thank you ! Sorry i'm not able to upvote a answer yet.